# Clase constructora genera objeto a partir del primer parámetro enviado

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de usar la clase constructora, estoy pasando diferentes parámetros por la clase constructora y al momento del envió de los datos a través de un formulario por html, me los guarda como si fuera un objeto del primer parámetro que coloqué en la clase constructora, en este caso seria username, guardanme adentro de username los parametros que estoy colocando (username, birthday, picture, email, password y repeatPassword) y deja los parámetros en si como undefined ya que todo se guarda adentro de username, se ve así:

```
User {   idUser: undefined,   username: {
    username: 'lola',
    birthday: '2022-03-01',
    picture: '1.jpg',
    email: 'lola@lola.com',
    password: '1234',
    repeatPassword: '1234'   },   
email: undefined,   
birthday: undefined,   
picture: undefined,   
password: undefined,   
repeatPassword: undefined
```

Mi codigo:

```
class User{
    idUser
    constructor(username, email, birthday, picture, password,repeatPassword){
        this.username = username
        this.email = email
        this.birthday = birthday
        this.picture = picture
        this.password = password
        this.repeatPassword = repeatPassword
    }
    static async readAll(){
        //como se devuelven todos, va asi
        return await query("SELECT * FROM users")
    }

    async save(){
        const newUser = await insert("usersp2",{
            username: this.username,
            birthday: this.birthday,
            email: this.email,
            picture: this.picture,
            password: this.password 
        })

        this.idUser = newUser.id

    }
```

////

```
 async signUp(req,res){
        const newUser = new User(req.body)
        const validation = newUser.validate()
        console.log(newUser)
        if(validation.sucess){
            await newUser.save()
            return res.redirect("/")
        }
```

///

Asi pido en el form:

```
<form action="/signup" method="POST" class="formLogin">
        <p>Username</p>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="" placeholder="Username..." value="{{user.username}}" required>
        <p>Birthday</p>
        <input type="date" name="birthday" id="" value="{{user.birthday}}" required>
        <p>Picture</p>
        <input type="text" name="picture" id="" placeholder="Picture..." value="{{user.picture}}" required>
        <p>Email</p>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="" placeholder="Email..." value="{{user.email}}" required>
        <p>Password</p>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="" placeholder="Password..." required><br>
        <p>Repeat password</p>
        <input type="password" name="repeatPassword" id="" placeholder="Repeat password..." required><br>
        <button class="btnLogin">Sign up</button>                        
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro, porque al método constructor (no es *clase constructora*) le estás pasando un objeto (`req.body`) y el constructor espera parámetros, por lo cual toma el objeto como valor del primer parámetro.

Prueba lo siguiente:

```js
const newUser = new User(req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.birthday);
```

Otra forma es deconstruir el objeto `body` usando la sintaxis `spread`, por ejemplo:

```js
const newUser = new User(...req.body);
```

Pero esto tiene el inconveniente de que los argumentos son posicionales y no hay garantía que el objeto `body` tenga el mismo orden de atributos en que esperas recibir los argumentos.

Por lo cual es mejor deconstruir el objeto en sus atributos constituyentes y luego pasar los argumentos en orden, por ejemplo:

```js
const {username, email, birthday} = req.body;
const user = new User(username, email, birthday);
```

Puedes leer más sobre la [sintaxis `spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) en la documentación.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Ahi me funciono! Muchas gracias Mauricio! Me habian enseñado que se llamaba clase constructora ‍♀️, ahora ademas aprendi que es un metodo! Gracias :D

Comment: Para no enredarte, todas las clases serían *constructoras* en Javascript, ya que puedes crear o instanciar objetos usando la palabra reservada `new` antepuesta al nombre de la Clase. Sin embargo, esto lo que hace, entre otras cosas, es llamar al método `constructor` de la Clase. Sería más exacto decir *el constructor User* y no *la Clase constructora*. Saludos